# probability question please using binomial?

Tags: probability

We have two machines which produce products of two qualities.The first machine produces 20 products in a hour of the first quality,and  8 products of the second quality.The second machine produces  30 products of the first quality and 9 products of the second quality.From one of the machines we take 2 products,which seem to be of the first quality.whats the probability that the products are from the first machine.?
so,my teacher told us that this is solved using binomial distribution but I dont think so at all.I think it can be solved using P(A/Hi)...
what do you think?

Answer (score 1):

There is a good case for saying you are both right! There are two interoretations of the data. (i) The (first) machine produces $28$ items per hour, exactly $20$ of of which are of the first quality, and $8$ of the second. Similar assumptions about the second. We choose one of the two machines at random, each with probbility $\frac{1}{2}$, and take a sample of $2$ from items produced that hour or (ii) the (first) machine produces $28$ items per hour. With probability $\frac{20}{28}$, an item produced by that machine is of the first quality, and with probability $\frac{8}{28}$ it is of the second quality. Similar assumptions about the second machine. (There are  actually other physically reasonable interpretations, that from the joint productions we take a sample of two. But they are **not** supported by the wording, which says that from *one* of the machines we take two items.)

We will use interpretation (ii), which is physically somewhat more reasonable than (i).

Let $B$ be the event the two items tested are both good, and let $F$ be the event they are from the first machine. We want $\Pr(F|B)$. As usual 
$$\Pr(F|B)=\frac{\Pr(F\cap B)}{\Pr(B)}.$$
We calculate the probabilities on the right.

Under interpretation (ii), we have
$$\Pr(F\cap B)=\frac{1}{2}\binom{28}{2}\left(\frac{20}{28}\right)^2 \left(\frac{8}{28}\right)^0.$$
Similarly, 
$$\Pr(B)=\frac{1}{2}\binom{28}{2}\left(\frac{20}{28}\right)^2 \left(\frac{8}{28}\right)^0+ \frac{1}{2}\binom{39}{2}\left(\frac{30}{39}\right)^2 \left(\frac{9}{39}\right)^0.$$

**Remark:** Under interpretation (i), we would have
$$\Pr(F\cap B)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\binom{20}{2}\binom{8}{0}}{\binom{28}{2}},$$
with a similarly constructed expression for $\Pr(B)$.